# Blender 3.0 geometry nodes - how to displace mesh using UV?

Tags: uv, displacement, geometry-nodes

I have created a mesh in geometry nodes from the curve and want to displace it. Currently, I am doing it by creating a UV attribute and using it in my material. How can I achieve the same result in geometry nodes?

[image: geometry node setup]

*Geometry node setup. Output UV_map is then stored in the UV_map attribute.*

[image: material setup]

*Material setup.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use noise texture in GN as well. To deform along normal, simply scale the normal vector by texture output. Subtract and multiply simulates mid-level and strength.

[image]